# On button push create and open folder, scan it for files

Tags: c#, winforms, file, directory

Could someone help me with one function... Im creating windows forms application in which on certain button push application creates folder (in apps .exe root directory) as example named Folder1, and after creating it also opens it.

EDiT: I have done it like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("CPC Folder");
    string myPath = @"CPC Folder";
    System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    prc.StartInfo.FileName = myPath;
    prc.Start();
}
```

This is first part, in second part after user put one .txt file in that folder I need help with scaning function, which would scan newly created folder for users imputed .txt file and when found it saved path to it to variable.

The main thing is with first part now. I will probably find a way to get second done... Hope anyone will help me :)

P.s. this app is based on c# and I for code I can only show this now:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Comment: Some code to review would be useful to include in your question.

Comment: At this moment I only have `        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }`

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do the first part all you would need is the following code:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("SomeDirectoryName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out this class: `FileSystemWatcher` 
[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
private string myTextFile;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string myPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\CPC Folder";
     System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(myPath);
     Process.Start("explorer.exe", myPath);
     FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(myPath, "*.txt");
     fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
     fileWatcher.Created += (snder, eArgs) =>
     {
         myTextFile = eArgs.FullPath;
     };
}
```